# Facebook Comment not picking right URL

Tags: facebook, comments

I am using facebook comments and providing the url of the page to distinguish. here is the code I am using

```
<?php $commenturl="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:comments href="<?php echo $commenturl?>" num_posts="8" width="670"></fb:comments>
```

My url is www.domain.com/foldername/index.php?etc.

so it shows up the comment feed ok, but once someone posts a comment the url on his wall omits the foldername and directly goes to mangoestv.com/index.php?etc.

what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem was solution was to use htaccess to rewrite url , because it seems that facebook considers domain.com/index.php?var=abc and domain.com/index.php?var=xyz the same

so you should have url like that domain.com/abc and domain.com/xyz

**Edit :**

info about rewriting url's

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: i don't understand what you mean....

so i should have a redirect setup where domain.com is being forwarded to domain.com/foldername?

Comment: ok i did this and seems to be working at my end now... thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: btw i did the rewrite like this
[inline]
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/foldername" [R=301,L]
[/inline]
the site does show up the right content but my facebook like counts are lost because the url add a ? after the foldername/ 
[inline]
domain.com/foldername/?index.php&etc.
[/inline]
it should be domain.com/foldername/index.php&etc.

anyway I can achieve that?